# PHP Login não carrega página

Tags: php, login

Meu sistema de login funciona direitinho na máquina, porém no servidor não.
Para na página valida.php, a qual pega as informações do formulário e verifica no BD as informações.

**login.php** - Formulário de Login

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<form method="POST" action="valida.php">
        <h2>Área Restrita</h2>
  <label>Login</label>
        <input name="email_cli" type="email" autofocus required placeholder="Email" maxlength="55">
  <label>Senha</label>
        <input type="password" name="senha_cli" placeholder="Senha (seu CPF)" required><br>
        <button type="submit" class="botao_cadastro">Acessar</button>
  </form>
    <p>
        <?php if(isset($_SESSION['loginErro'])){
            echo $_SESSION['loginErro'];
            unset($_SESSION['loginErro']);
        }?>
    </p>
    <p>
        <?php 
        if(isset($_SESSION['logindeslogado'])){
            echo $_SESSION['logindeslogado'];
            unset($_SESSION['logindeslogado']);
        }
        ?>
    </p>
```

**valida.php** - Página que faz a validação dos dados e redireciona

```
<?php
session_start(); 
    //Incluindo a conexão com banco de dados   
include_once("conexao.php");    
//O campo usuário e senha preenchido entra no if para validar
if((isset($_POST['email_cli'])) && (isset($_POST['senha_cli']))){
    $usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email_cli']); //Escapar de caracteres especiais, como aspas, prevenindo SQL injection
    $senha = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['senha_cli']);
    $senha = md5($senha);

    //Buscar na tabela usuario o usuário que corresponde com os dados digitado no formulário
    $result_usuario = "SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE email_cli = '$usuario' && senha_cli = '$senha' LIMIT 1";
    $resultado_usuario = mysqli_query($conn, $result_usuario);
    $resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_usuario);

    //Encontrado um usuario na tabela usuário com os mesmos dados digitado no formulário
    if(isset($resultado)){
        $_SESSION['usuarioId'] = $resultado['id_cli'];
        $_SESSION['usuarioNome'] = $resultado['nome_cli'];
        $_SESSION['usuarioNiveisAcessoId'] = $resultado['nivel'];
        $_SESSION['usuarioEmail'] = $resultado['email_cli'];
        if($_SESSION['usuarioNiveisAcessoId'] == "2"){
            header("Location: video_aulas_profissional.php");
        }elseif($_SESSION['usuarioNiveisAcessoId'] == "1"){
            header("Location: video_aulas_basicos.php");
        }else{
            header("Location: login.php");
        }
    //Não foi encontrado um usuario na tabela usuário com os mesmos dados digitado no formulário
    //redireciona o usuario para a página de login
    }else{    
        //Váriavel global recebendo a mensagem de erro
        $_SESSION['loginErro'] = "Usuário ou senha Inválido";
        header("Location: login.php");
    }
//O campo usuário e senha não preenchido entra no else e redireciona o usuário para a página de login
}else{
    $_SESSION['loginErro'] = "Usuário ou senha inválido";
    header("Location: login.php");
}
?>
```

**conexao.php** - Conecta ao BD

```
    <?php
$servidor = "localhost";
$usuario = "turkish";
$senha = "123456";
$dbname = "usuarios";

//Criar a conexao
$conn = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $senha, $dbname);

if(!$conn){
    die("Falha na conexao: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}else{
    //echo "Conexao realizada com sucesso";
}

?>
```

Comment: Alguma mensagem de erro? Você atualizou o `conexao.php` para os dados do servidor?

Comment: Não exibe nenhum erro e alterei sim.

Comment: A página é mostrada, ou fica branca? Ou o que acontece? Dê detalhes. Se possível, veja se aparece alguma mensagem de erro no console do navegador

Comment: Para na página valida.php e fica branca. Não aparece nenhum erro no console.

Comment: As páginas: video_aulas_profissional.php e video_aulas_basicos.php, para onde tem que redirecionar após o login, foram subidas no servidor? O caminho delas estão corretos?

Answer (score 1):

O código é capaz de esta a ter dificuldades nesta linha, porque a variavél foi **definida**, mas tem é um valor **.

```
if(isset($resultado)){
```

Deveria ser algo do tipo

```
if($resultado!=null){
```

Também é possível o servidor estar a bugar em login.php com as variáveis de **SESSÃO**

Answer (score 0):

Não sei que sistema de BD está a utilizar mas de certeza que:

```
$result_usuario = "SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE email_cli = '$usuario' && senha_cli = '$senha' LIMIT 1";


$result_usuario = "SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE email_cli = '$usuario' AND senha_cli = '$senha' LIMIT 1";
```

Esse poderá ser o problema visto que provavelmente não tem os logging de erros aparecer no PHP ativados, ele poderá estar a "estourar" na query logo a página aparece branca em vez de dar o erro.

Comment: João. Ativei os logs de erro mas não aparece nada. Nem no console. Troquei **email_cli = '$usuario' && senha_cli = '$senha** por **email_cli = '$usuario' AND senha_cli = '$senha** e também não funcionou.